# Expo push-notifications are not working on Android APK Build

Tags: android, firebase, react-native, push-notification, expo

I am trying to send Notifications for the Android App I created with React Native and Expo. The problem is that the Notifications are working when I start my App with Expo Go, but when I am trying to send Notifications with my APK Build, it does not work.

I followed all the steps from [this expo guide](https://docs.expo.dev/push-notifications/push-notifications-setup/), but it still does not work and I dont know why. I tried to send the Notifications with my Code and also with [this expo push notification tool](https://expo.dev/notifications). In both cases I won`t get any error message and I am not recieving a Notification with my APK build.

I hope you could help me with this.

Thanks in advance

Orchi

Answer (score 0):

In my case the problem was I've added Notifications.setNotificationChannelAsync code, once removed it started working.